# Regex for Tomcat error logs

Tags: python, regex, tomcat, logging

Consider the following Tomcat log structure:

```
[06/Feb/2013:15:25:27 +0000] [Thread-10] DEBUG xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.BlahBlahClass  - Reloading blah configuration: /somepath/xxx.yyy
[06/Feb/2013:15:25:27 +0000] [Thread-11] ERROR xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.BlahBlahClass2  - [xxx.yyy] - Could not find the somethinh
[06/Feb/2013:15:25:27 +0000] [Thread-12] ERROR xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy  - error handling product : xxx.yyy  don't know where it is 
xxx.yyy.IOException: Could not find the feed with id [thisisfeedname_13601429613239870] in the feed repository or as a what?
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy(xxx.yyy:57)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy(xxx.yyy:65)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.flush(xxx.yyy:294)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.DelayedLogger$xxx.yyy(Unknown Source)
Caused by: xxx.yyy.FileNotFoundException: /path/to/feeds/xxx.yyy (No such file or directory)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy(Native Method)
    at xxx.yyy.FileInputStream.<init>(xxx.yyy:120)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.parse(xxx.yyy:248)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy$xxx.yyy(Unknown Source)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy(xxx.yyy:41)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy(xxx.yyy:13)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy(xxx.yyy:54)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy(xxx.yyy:176)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy(xxx.yyy:151)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy(xxx.yyy:143)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy(xxx.yyy:127)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy(xxx.yyy:63)
    at xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy(xxx.yyy:43)
    ... 3 more
[06/Feb/2013:15:25:27 +0000] [Thread-13] INFO  xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy  - constructing a new CSV feed resource
[06/Feb/2013:15:25:27 +0000] [Thread-14] DEBUG xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy  - number of feeds defined for the resource: 1
[06/Feb/2013:15:25:27 +0000] [Thread-15] INFO  xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy  - constructing a new CSV feed resource
```

The log consists of a report line that begins with a timestamp in braces, optionally followed by a stack trace. For example, `Thread-12` has a following stack trace, but threads 10 through 15 don't.

I'd like to convert each log event into a Python object with timestamp, error type (`ERROR`, `INFO` etc), message and optional stack trace. I've tried the following regex:

```
reg_str='^\[(.*?)\]\s+\[(.*?)\]\s+(\w+)\s*(.*)\s*$\s*(([^\[].*?$)*)'
reg=re.compile(reg_str, re.MULTILINE)
```

[Alas](http://mentalfloss.com/article/28737/words-used-incorrectly-alas), whenever there's a stack trace, the regex greedily matches the text till the end of the log.

How can I rewrite the regex to match the log events correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make the greedy part non-greedy ;)

```
^\[(.*?)\]\s+\[(.*?)\]\s+(\w+)\s*(.*?)\s*$\s*(([^\[].*?$)*)
                                    ^
```

Here's [a Rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/VXPBeGXyd4).

You can see in the link, though, that there's a problem with the rest of the regex. First, what you need to do is put the last `\s*` *within* the parentheses, since the optional lines can be indented. Second, you need to use a negative lookahead instead of a negated character class, for a reason that may complicate this answer to explain (but I can, in a comment, if you'd like). Like so:

```
^\[(.*?)\]\s+\[(.*?)\]\s+(\w+)\s*(.*?)\s*$((\s*(?!\[).*?$)*)
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here's [another Rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/ZgoJFeCioI).

Finally, that last capturing group isn't particularly useful, so...

```
^\[(.*?)\]\s+\[(.*?)\]\s+(\w+)\s*(.*?)\s*$((?:\s*(?!\[).*?$)*)
                                            ^^
```

Here's [the final Rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/7KaD6dC0js).